# NodeJS: Controlling the order of loading modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

Here is the scenario:
I have 3 files (modules):

**app.js**

```js
(async () => {
  await connectoDB();
  let newRec = new userModel({
    ...someprops
  });
  await newRec.save();
})();
```

The `app.ts` is the entry point of the project.

**database.ts**

```js
interface ConnectionInterface {
  [name: string]: mongoose.Connection;
}

export class Connection {
  public static connections: ConnectionInterface;

  public static async setConnection(name: string, connection: mongoose.Connection) {
    Connection.connections = {
      ...Connection.connections,
      [name]: connection,
    };
  }
}

export async function connectToDB() {
  const conn = await mongoose.createConnection('somePath');
  await Connection.setConnection('report', conn);
}
```

**model.ts**

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ..someprops
  },
);

const userModel = Connection.connections.report.model('User', userSchema);
export default userModel;
```

**What I am trying to do:** I need to have multiple mongoose connections, so I use an static prop called `connections` in `Connection` class (in `database.ts`); every time that I connect to a database I use `setConnection` to store the connection in mentioned static prop, so I can access it from every module in my project by its name which is `report` in this case.

Later, In `model.ts` I use `Connection.connections.report` to access the connection `report` to load my model!

Then, When I run `app.ts` I get the following error which is logical:

```
const aggregationModel = Connection.connections.report.model('User', userSchema)
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'report' of undefined
```

The reason that causes this (I think) is, while loading imported modules in `app.ts`, `.report` is not declared because the `app.ts` isn't run completely (`connectoDB()` defines the `.report` key).

> The codes that I have mentioned have been simplified for preventing complexity. The original app is an express app!

Now, How should I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the connection to finish before using it if you change up your class slightly.

```
const connection = await Connection.getConnection()
const model = connection.example

...

class Connection {
  ...

  public static async getConnection() => {
    if (!Connection.connection) {
      await Connection.setConnection()
    }

    return Connection.connection
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a function as: ```public static getConnections() {
    return Connection.connections;
  }```. And tried to access the report like: ```Connection.getConnections().report```, Is it correct? That didn't make a change.

Comment: It didn't make a change because you didn't actually change anything, you just returned the same connections as before.  You need to check if those connections exist and delay the promise from resolving until they have actually been created.  In this case you're just returning undefined from the getConnections.

Comment: @Matriax Can you please clarify how should I wait? also a tiny code will be helpful. Thanks for your time :)